# Какие есть контексты в веб-приложении и чем они отличаются?

Tags: java, java-ee, web-apps

Какие есть контексты в веб-приложении и чем они отличаются?
Из прочитанного в инете не могу понять понятие "контекст" в данном случае, вероятно руки не из того места и криво гуглю, если кто-сможет объяснить или дать линк на инфу, буду признателен, то что мне подсказали относительно моего вопроса: "Их там несколько - запроса, сессии, приложения, сервера".

Comment: Отличаются информацией, функциями, характерными для контекста данного типа, областью видимости этой информации. Как глобальные, локальные переменные.

Comment: Возможно, вы не правильно поняли контекст слова "контекст" (извините за каламбур). Скорее всего, вы имеете в виду часть спецификации CDI ( Context (!) and Dependency Injection). В этой спецификации управляемые компоненты имеют контекст - область видимости и существования компонента. Крайне советую прочитать книгу "Изучаем Java EE 7". Там рассказывается и про CDI, и про остальные центральные спецификации вроде EJB, JPA и т.д.

Comment: Читать про контекст, не понимая сути DI бессмысленно, так что лучше изучите всё по порядку.

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев спасибо за советы, уже разобрался в контекстах.